# Installing pycrypto on windows (popular solution not working)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, python, pip

This is a traight up copy of my question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775935/installing-pycrypto-on-windows-popular-solution-not-working?noredirect=1#comment107529112_60775935).

I got a comment recommending posting it here as well since it is more of an environment thing.

I need to install pycrypto for a project that requires pycrypto. PyCryptodome is not an option, sadly.

I have tried what everybody seems to recommend, aka powershell commands proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843266/microsoft-windows-python-3-6-pycrypto-installation-error?noredirect=1&lq=1) but to no avail.

I set `VCINSTALLDIR` in my user vars to 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\`.
I double checked that `stdint.h` is indeed at `VCINSTALLDOR\Tool\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\`. I then ran

`set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDOR%Tool\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\stdint.h"`

and

`pip install pycrypto`

still no luck. Tried it both with and without admin privileges.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When I am having problems like this.. I use WSL.  Works every time and you will be able use Linux help to solve your problem and not have to fight windows ports or less documentation.

Comment: Can I install the package in WSL and use them in Windows directly?

Comment: "Use them in windows directly.." I am not sure what you mean.. but I think the answer would be yes.  I can pipe information from cmd.exe, into bash, sort it (or whatever), then into powershell.exe to do something else with it.. seamlessly.  Play with it..;) you will see.

Comment: True, my comment was a bit ambiguous. I need a way to be able to import the package in a python script under windows. Meaning I need the compiled library available on windows.

Comment: OH.. no, you could not use WSL Linux Python with a windows dynamic library.. Sorry.. I gotz nothing for you Harri.  Good luck! :)

Comment: You may want to expand on the issue that you are (still) having. The solution(s) proposed in your link worked for me during a test install to a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It's easier to use pycryptodome, that has the same name when you use it. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/1647238)

```
pip uninstall crypto 
pip uninstall pycrypto 
pip install pycryptodome
```

---

For the installation of vstools (Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0) I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49986365) answer

Now be sure that you had located acuratelly the next 2 paths (Mine below):

**vcvars*.bat** (choose file name depending on VC version and architecture): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build`

**stdint.h**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include`

In a command shell

1. Go to the vsvars*.bat location

   cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build
2. Run vsvars*.bat depending on VC version and architecture

   vcvars64.bat
3. Set the stdint.h location, without close the shell

   set CL=-FI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdint.h"
4. Install pycrypto again

   pip install pycrypto